# Scikit-learnのGridSearchCVについて

Tags: python, scikit-learn

初歩的な質問で申し訳ありません。
Scikit learnのGridSearchCVはグリッドサーチだけでなく、引数cv=5とすれば５分割の交差検証も行ってくれるのですか？
ご存じありましたら、ご回答いただけたらと思います。
よろしくお願いします。

（グリッドサーチと交差検証について学んでおりまして、グリッドサーチに関してはそれなりにできたのですが、交差検証の方がいろいろと手こずっていたのですが、、「Scikit-learnのGridSearchCVで簡単にできる」「引数からCV=」で入力するだけと聞いて「そんなに簡単にできるの」と少々驚き、「勘違いでないか？」と確認のために質問させていただきました。）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

はい。交差検証を用いたグリッドサーチは、パラメーターチューニングで一般的に使われるので、scikit-learnでは（`GridSearchCV`に）実装済みです。

Comment: 書き込みありがとうございます。

GridSearchCVで交差検証もできるとは、なんｋだとてもよいものを手に入れた気分です。
写経プログラマレベルなので、とりあえず今はGridSearchCVで使っていこうと思います。

書き込みありがとうございました。